# How to use the value of one variable when checking the existence of another

Tags: php

I want to be able to check the existence of up to, but often less than, 6 consecutively named variables using a FOR loop thus:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
   $vartocheck = "$var_".$i;
   if ($vartocheck) {
      echo $vartocheck." exists!";
   }
}
```

Now I know the above doesn't work but I can't figure out how to reference and check the existence of $var_0 through to $var_5 by using the value of $i.

I have tried isset and call_user_func to construct and return the variable name I am after but I have had no success thus far.

I am trying to avoid an eval statement.

Comment: It really sounds like your vars should be in an array instead of just independently named variables.

Comment: You can always use eval (which is in no way evil) :-) ...

Comment: Hmm, possibly. At the moment I am working with the system as it is and I know that the variable have been declared so I am trying to work with that first.

Comment: `if (isset(${"var_{$i}"}))` looks to be the most direct way.

Comment: @adeneo no. just no. Never use `eval` unless you have an overpoweringly strong reason and you have completely exhausted all other *sane* alternatives.

Comment: @Sammitch - It was meant as a joke, but in this case the OP has full control over what is being eval'ed, so it should'nt really be an issue, and if used properly, it really is'nt evil at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct way looks to be :

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  if (isset(${"var_{$i}"})) {
    echo ${"var_{$i}"}." exists!";
  }
}
```

Note that :

```
$hello = 'world';
$world = 'foo';

$$hello === ${$hello} === ${"world"} === $world === 'foo'.
```

So in your original code, you can use :

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
   $vartocheck = "var_".$i;
   if (isset($$vartocheck)) {
      echo '$'.$vartocheck." exists!";
   }
}
```

Comment: Until I can sort the array-based solution, this is exactly what I needed. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it (because it's just wrong to dynamically check the existence of variables by name), but it can be done using for example:

```
isset($$vartocheck);
```

Responding to your comment, this works:

```
<?php
    $var = 'abc';
    var_dump(isset($$var)); // bool(false)
    $abc = 1;
    var_dump(isset($$var)); // bool(true)
```

Check if you don't have special characters inside your $vartocheck (whitespaces etc.) or if the variable is really a string.

Comment: Krzysztof - not sure what you mean by "Don't do it because it's just wrong". Also, I have tried using isset within the if statement but to no avail.

Comment: Note the double `$` signs. It reads the value of `$vartocheck` and tries the value as a name for the variable. It's wrong to do this because it can lead to a collision with existing variables. Say you have another variable in the scope which you don't want to check, it will return true for that variable too. If the data comes from user it might be a security issue.

Comment: Put all of those variables in an `array` and check them using `array_key_exists` or `isset`. You can also iterate over them much easier.

Comment: Ah, right. I did try that ($$) but had no success. The array-based solution is now on my "To Do" list but at least I have a working solution from ninsuo.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$var_4 = "Test";
for($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i ++) {
    $vartocheck = "var_" . $i;
    if (isset(${$vartocheck})) {
        echo $vartocheck, " exists!";
    }
}
```

Output

```
var_4 exists!
```

Comment: Thanks Baba. The solution below from Ninsuo is even more compact so I'll go with that for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$$var_name`

modified version of your code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
   $vartocheck = "var_".$i;
   if (isset($$vartocheck)) {
      echo $vartocheck." exists!";
   }
}
```

ps: +1 for using arrays.

Comment: Hey there, I did try that but had no success. As for the Array, I shall add that to my "To Do" list once I have this all working as I need for proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it. It's poor practice to dynamically check the existence of variables by name, but if you must it can be done by the following:

```
isset($$vartocheck);
```

However, as @paolo-bergantino noted in the comments, you're much better off using an array for things like this.

Comment: Hey there, I did try that but had no success.